# Mosquitto-PHP Library in raspberry and windows

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I install PHP client for MQTT using Mosquitto-PHP

Library in raspberry
[mosquitto php library](http://wingsquare.com/blog/developing-php-client-for-mqtt-using-mosquitto-php-library)/

after that create pub.php in `/var/www/html/mqtt` when write in browser `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/mqtt/pup.php` and no see any data

I then tried

```
$mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "/mqtt" -m "HelloWorld"
```

and the get

```
bash: -h: command not found
```

I don't know where the problem is, for information write in command

```
$mosquitto -v
1464002857: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Tue, 17 May 2016 11:26:59 +0100) starting
1464002857: Using default config.
1464002857: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1464002857:Error: Address already in use
```

I also have the same problem in my windows I install mosquitto, see this link [step-by-step-installing-and-configuring-mosquitto-with-windows-7](https://sivatechworld.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/step-by-step-installing-and-configuring-mosquitto-with-windows-7/)

I see the service for Mosquitto Broker(MQTT v3.1 broker) is runnng and
check the example pub.php to testing the result is error `Mosquitto\Client()` is not found

I searched and found mosquitto.php and put the I put this code in pub.php

```
require "mosquitto.php";
```

I don't know where the problem is, can any one help me to running mosquitto in my windows and raspberry.

I need to try mqtt connected with localhost and check connection is OK or not also to subscribe and publish and reading the message

Comment: for informaton 
i find mosquitto.php from this link
https://github.com/Nakard/mosquitto-stub/blob/master/mosquitto.php

also Iam using code pub.php from this link
https://github.com/mgdm/Mosquitto-PHP/blob/master/examples/pub.php

Comment: This is a little rambling, The best questions cover a single problem. If you can break it up into separate parts you will likely do better

Comment: thank you sir 
the problem is i try to running mosquitto with php to connect with localhost and can be publish and subsribe , for me i try in raspberry or windows but no find the problem , 
I need to runnig mosquitto with php and can be  connected with localhost and check connection is OK or not also to subscribe and publish and reading the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this information to install mosquittolib with php  in raspberry

```
 wget http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-repo.gpg.key

sudo apt-key add mosquitto-repo.gpg.key

cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

sudo wget http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-jessie.list

sudo apt-get update

apt-get install mosquitto

sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients

sudo apt-get install php5-dev

sudo apt-get install libmosquitto-dev

sudo pecl install Mosquitto-alpha
```

and in /etc/php5/mods-available/mosquitto.ini

add this code

```
extension=mosquitto.so
```

this code for check version of the Mosquitto library

```
dpkg -l | grep mosquito
```

and the end enabled that with sudo php5enmod mosquitto

```
 sudo php5enmod mosquitto
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > ~/tester.php
php ~/tester.php
```

**code pub.php**

```
   <?php

$client = new Mosquitto\Client();
$client->onConnect('connect');
$client->onDisconnect('disconnect');
$client->onPublish('publish');
$client->connect("localhost", 1883, 5);

while (true) {
        try{
                $client->loop();
                $mid = $client->publish('/hasan', "Hello from PHP");
                $client->loop();
        }catch(Mosquitto\Exception $e){
                return;
        }
        sleep(2);
}

$client->disconnect();
unset($client);

function connect($r) {
        echo "I got code {$r}\n";
}

function publish() {
        global $client;
        echo "Mesage published\n";
        $client->disconnect();
}

function disconnect() {
        echo "Disconnected cleanly\n";
}
```

**code sub.php**

```
     <?php

$client = new Mosquitto\Client();
$client->onConnect('connect');
$client->onDisconnect('disconnect');
$client->onSubscribe('subscribe');
$client->onMessage('message');
$client->connect("localhost", 1883, 60);
$client->subscribe('/hasan', 1);


while (true) {
        $client->loop();
        sleep(2);
}

$client->disconnect();
unset($client);

function connect($r) {
        echo "I got code {$r}\n";
}

function subscribe() {
        echo "Subscribed to a topic\n";
}

function message($message) {
        printf("\nGot a message on topic %s with payload:%s", 
                $message->topic, $message->payload);
}

function disconnect() {
        echo "Disconnected cleanly\n";
}
```

[test sub.php and pub.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY8zG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error when starting the broker is because mosquitto is already running as a service. If you want to run it in the foreground in verbose mode you will have to stop it first.

Run the following on the TRaspberry Pi to stop the service.

```
sudo service stop mosquitto
```

The error with `mosquitto_pub` implies that you are pressing return between `mosquitto` and the `-h localhost...`

The PHP problems should be raised as a separate question.

Comment: thank you sir , I try to write command sudo service stop mosquitto  ,and try again to test and the same problem

Comment: can be using this information or this old

https://rasspberrypi.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/mosquitto-mqtt-on-raspberry-pi-broker-publish-and-subscribe-client/

Answer (score 0):

Now is work 
in Install this commands in this link
http://mosquitto.org/2013/01/mosquitto-debian-repository/

also install mosquitto-clients

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients
```

after that Iam using this commands to test

```
$ mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.2 -d -t hello/world
```

and

```
$ mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.2 -d -t hello/world -m "Message To Send"
```

Where 192.168.1.2 is your Raspberry Pi’s IP Address
please see this link
https://rasspberrypi.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/mosquitto-mqtt-on-raspberry-pi-broker-publish-and-subscribe-client/

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mosquitto_sub -h 210.201.4.114 -d -t hello/world

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp sending CONNECT

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp received CONNACK

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: hello/world, QoS: 0)

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp sending PINGREQ

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp received PINGRESP

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp sending PINGREQ

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp received PINGRESP

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'hello/world', ... (15 bytes))

Message To Send

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp sending PINGREQ

Client mosqsub/1796-raspberryp received PINGRESP

============================================

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mosquitto_pub -h 210.201.4.114 -d -t hello/world -m "Message To Send"

Client mosqpub/1800-raspberryp sending CONNECT

Client mosqpub/1800-raspberryp received CONNACK

Client mosqpub/1800-raspberryp sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 'hello/world', ... (15 bytes))

Client mosqpub/1800-raspberryp sending DISCONNECT

Answer (score 0):

Now I need test code pub.php and sub.php how can doing it

I put sup.php & pub.php in /var/www/html

sub.php

```
 <?php

$client = new Mosquitto\Client();
$client->onConnect('connect');
$client->onDisconnect('disconnect');
$client->onSubscribe('subscribe');
$client->onMessage('message');
$client->connect("localhost", 1883, 60);
$client->subscribe('/#', 1);


while (true) {
        $client->loop();
        sleep(2);
}

$client->disconnect();
unset($client);

function connect($r) {
        echo "I got code {$r}\n";
}

function subscribe() {
        echo "Subscribed to a topic\n";
}

function message($message) {
        printf("\nGot a message on topic %s with payload:%s", 
                $message->topic, $message->payload);
}

function disconnect() {
        echo "Disconnected cleanly\n";
}
```

pub.php

```
   <?php

$client = new Mosquitto\Client();
$client->onConnect('connect');
$client->onDisconnect('disconnect');
$client->onPublish('publish');
$client->connect("localhost", 1883, 5);

while (true) {
        try{
                $client->loop();
                $mid = $client->publish('/mqtt', "Hello from PHP");
                $client->loop();
        }catch(Mosquitto\Exception $e){
                return;
        }
        sleep(2);
}

$client->disconnect();
unset($client);

function connect($r) {
        echo "I got code {$r}\n";
}

function publish() {
        global $client;
        echo "Mesage published\n";
        $client->disconnect();
}

function disconnect() {
        echo "Disconnected cleanly\n";
}
```

Comment: I write this command

pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/t $ php pub.php



, the result is PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mosquitto.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mosquitto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mosquitto\Client' not found in /var/www/html/t/pub.php on line 3

Comment: Now is work ,
1- write in command  cd /var/www/html

2- after that write php sub.php

anthor open window and write also 

1- write in command  cd /var/www/html

2- after that write php pub.php